# how to add first ListView Item to the bottom of screen

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

am building a chat UI,, so wanted to know if  there is any possible way to add first ListView Item to the bottom of the screen 
Note: the Item is a text message ,, so everytime a text massage is send it should show on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the FlexboxLayout with column-reverse property.
You can also align the items on the left or right side,  so i think this is perfect for you.

watch this for more detail: 
https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers

at the bottom there is flexbox layout.

Comment: thats is exactly what am looking for

Comment: if this fix your problem you can accept my answer :) happy coding!